# network connectivity abnormal. Destination host unreachable

Tags: windows, internet, ping, exchange, windows-server-2012

we have a 2012 server's nic showing connected to internet but cant ping 8.8.8.8

firewall returns Destination host unreachable though firewall can reach internet.

it can ping firewall. all other devices can reach internet.

i checked in the firewall and saw ping was allowed and packet was delivered.

safe mode is the same result

restarting the server and using another nic doesnt help.

this server is for exchange and although it cant send mail, it can receive.

anyone know how to fix it?

regards

Comment: What do you mean in the firewall you saw "ping was allowed and packet was delivered?" This sounds like your firewall is blocking the traffic. If the server can ping the firewall, and it can receive e-mail from external sources but can't connect out - that is the firewall doing that. It's a bad NAT policy or something. You can't see if a packet was "delivered." At best you can see if a packet left the external interface of your router, after that you have no idea what happened to that packet.

Comment: i can see it was passed in the firewall instead of blocked. i created a new policy just for this server but no luck. firewall is fortigate 100d. all other servers work fine in the existing policy.

Comment: It is common practice to isolate email servers on a different public IP address. This usually happens when a customer purchases a block of IP addresses to use. In the firewall this usually means custom NAT rules. I can’t tell you why the firewall is blocking things, but it sure sounds like a NAT issue to me. Can you confirm, are you routing email traffic through a different public IP address? That would be a difference between this server, and “all other servers.” There’s too many unknown factors here to tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: yes, we have some public ips for our mail server. do you mean there are nat rules defined by the isp instead of our firewall? however, if so, i see in our firewall there are only inbound rules related to exchange server. outbound rule is just from lan to any destination. i tried to disable nat in the rule in our firewall but nothing changed.

Comment: ps. just by passed the firewall and it can go out to internet using public ip. how can i identify what blocked the traffic?

Answer (score 0):

somehow after switching nic back and forth a couple times it works now. still dont know what happened.